# Class for picture view that change pic on mouse click

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I want to make a class that has a picture and it is changed to the next one by mouse click.I'm new to oop, my idea here was to make class similar to real life where there is new class instance for every new picture, is it possible to do it this way? Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
class Picture():
    _count=1
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.id=Picture._count
        Picture._count+=1
        self.img=Image.open(r'C:\ImgArchive\img%s.png' % self.id)
        self.pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.lab=tk.Label(window,image=self.pimg)
        self.lab.pack()
        self.lab.bind('<1>',self.click)
    def click(self,event):
        self.lab.destroy()
        self=self.__init__(window)
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Album')
window.geometry('1200x900')
pic=Picture(window)
window.mainloop()
```

It works fine, but i'm not sure that old instances of my class is deleted, are they? And i use self.lab.destroy() because if i dont new picture appears down, like this

[image: #]

instead of this

[image: #]

So why it happens?What is elegant way for it?

Comment: command `self = self.__init__(...)` is the most unusual line of code - it means that you have to better organize code and move some code from `__init__` to separated method - and then run this method insife `__init__` and in place of `self = self.__init__()`

Comment: Better use `self.lab["image"] = new_image` to replace image in existing label.

Comment: i tried this `def click(self,event):
        self.lab.destroy()
        Picture._count+=1
        self.img=Image.open(r'C:\ImgArchive\img%s.png' % Picture._count)
        self.newImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.lab["image"] = self.newImg` but get error `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"` I'm new to oop, my idea here was to make class similar to real life where there is new class instance for every new picture, is it possible to do some way?

Comment: put it in question, it will be more readable.

Comment: if you want to change image in label then DON'T destroy it.

Comment: in real program I wouldn't  create new instance for new picture because it needs more time and memory. Besides sometimes it is hard to put new label/widget in the same place in GUI.

Comment: my bad, just noticed it too, yep this works good

Answer (score 0):

Below example produces a simple image viewer tested with path of `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures`, let me know if anything's unclear:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#required for getting files in a path
import os

class ImageViewer(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master, path):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.path = path
        self.image_index = 0

        self.list_image_files()
        self.show_image()

        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.show_next_image)

    def list_files(self):
        (_, _, filenames) = next(os.walk(self.path))
        return filenames

    def list_image_files(self):
        self.image_files = list()
        for a_file in self.list_files():
            if a_file.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg')):
                self.image_files.append(a_file)

    def show_image(self):
        img = Image.open(self.path + "\\" + self.image_files[self.image_index])
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self['image'] = self.img

    def show_next_image(self, *args):
        self.image_index = (self.image_index + 1) % len(self.image_files)
        self.show_image()

root = tk.Tk()

mypath = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures"
a = ImageViewer(root, mypath)
a.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. Now i see the pattern: inherit from Label class so i can use method to change the pic