# Showing pictures from the list of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I'd like to show pictures from list of files.gif in catalog, the pictures should change every 3s. 
I did try different solution but either is shown only firs pic or nothing.

TIA

```
    from  tkinter import *
import os
path = os.getcwd()
arr = []
for files in next(os.walk('/home/vimart/Python/img/'))[2]:
        arr.append('/home/vimart/Python/img' + "/" + files)
canvas_width = 300
canvas_height =300

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master,
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

def display():
        canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=canvas.img)


def get_picture():
        for  picture in arr:
                canvas.img = PhotoImage(picture)
                master.after(3000, display)
get_picture()

mainloop()
```

Comment: If you google "tkinter slideshow" you will find many examples how to do this.

Comment: don't use `for` - it displasy all image at once and you see only last one. Use `after()` to execute function which display only one image - and use global variable to remeber which image it was and do `next_image += 1`,  `picture = arr[next_image]`.

Comment: You may want to see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869161/7032856) for a similar image viewer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it doesn't need description.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
import os

# --- functions ---

def get_filenames(path):
    result = []

    #for one_file in os.listdir(path):
    for one_file in next(os.walk(path))[2]:
        if one_file.lower().endswith('.gif'): # sugessted by Nae
            result.append(path + one_file)

    return result

def display():
    global current_index

    picture = arr[current_index]
    canvas.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=picture)
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor='nw', image=canvas.img)

    current_index = (current_index + 1) % len(arr)

    master.after(3000, display)

# --- main ---

path = '/home/vimart/Python/img/'

arr = get_filenames(path)
current_index = 0

canvas_width  = 300
canvas_height = 300

master = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

display()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could add file-type filtering by adding `if one_file.lower().endswith('.gif'):` before appending too.

Comment: @Nae you are right. I was thinking about this when I add `os.listdir` but finally I skip this. Now it is added.